# "scoop" package manager can't install anything (or I think something's wrong with making secure connections)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, https, tls, scoop

I usually use scoop to manage my various packages on Windows. I haven't updated in a while but I recently tried to install an application via scoop and it gave me the following error:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
URL https://download.blender.org/release/Blender3.4/blender-3.4.1-windows-x64.zip is not valid
```

My internet isn't showing any problems or slowdowns and this error happens to any application I try to install.

I'm not sure what I did in the past that caused this since I haven't used scoop for a while but I was able to use it prior and have a few applications installed using it.

It should be noted that I also tried downloading a file via PowerShell using `Invoke-WebRequest` and I found out that while I could download files over an HTTP connection, I get an error when the file is hosted on HTTPS. I feel like these two things are connected somehow. Where I have some issues with connecting to secure connections.

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/paintdotnet/release/releases/do ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

However, my browser is working fine and can connect to secure sites no problem. How do I even go about trying to fix this? Does it have something to do with TLS somehow?

**EDIT:**
If you're going to downvote my post, at least explain why, I'm always open for conversation.

---

**Update 1:**
I'm still trying to figure this out but I've got more information to share just based on my testing.

1. This issue doesn't occur when I am directly connected via ethernet cable or from my phone's mobile hotspot using mobile data which is weird because I thought it had something to do with the problematic laptop's Wifi.
2. This issue is specifically on my device and not my router/etc because I tried connecting a different laptop to the same wifi and I can make secure connections immediately.
3. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the WiFi driver to no avail.

It's a whole tangled mess.

---

**Update 2:**
I have discovered that connecting to the 2.4Ghz SSID of my router fixes the issue however, this is the first time I've ever done this. I've always connected to 5Ghz as well as the other laptops that didn't have this issue so it has to be something about the driver or something? Plus, the mobile hotspot I mentioned on **Update 1** where the issue wasn't happening was broadcasting a 5Ghz network.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078682/net-httpwebrequest-https-error

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, do I have to write a C# application?

Comment: From that URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169222/how-do-you-get-a-system-web-httpwebrequest-object-to-use-ssl-2-0 , if the issue is SSL2.0